# change a prop in list of object in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array of object in JSON and want to change one value's properties.
for example assume I have a key field which is unique and `amount`, `name` props.
my approach is to find an object in the list with `findIndex` or map then remove it and make a new object and push to it. is this good way?
can recommend better approach or functions?

Comment: Why would you remove the object and then add it again ? Simply change the object ?

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović: A major theme in functional programming is to avoid mutating data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Lenses`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens) might be the canonical way to deal with this, although Ramda has a number of alternatives.

```
const people = [
  {id: 1, name: 'fred', age: 28},
  {id: 2, name: 'wilma', age: 25},
  {id: 3, name: 'barney', age: 27},
  {id: 4, name: 'betty', age: 29},  
]

const personIdx = name => findIndex(propEq('name', name), people)
const ageLens = idx => lensPath([idx, 'age'])

const wLens = ageLens(personIdx('wilma'))

const newPeople = over(wLens, age => age + 1, people)
//=> [
//     {id: 1, name: 'fred', age: 28},
//     {id: 2, name: 'wilma', age: 26},
//     {id: 3, name: 'barney', age: 27},
//     {id: 4, name: 'betty', age: 29},  
//   ]
```

Note that although `newPeople` is a brand new object, it shares as much as it can with the existing `people`.  For instance, `newPeople[3] === people[3] //=> true`.

Also note that as well as adjusting a parameter with this lens using [`over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over), we could simply fetch the value using [`view`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#view):

```
view(wLens, people) //=> 25
```

Or we could set it to a fixed value with [`set`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#set):

```
set(wLens, 42, people) //=> new version of `people` with wilma's age at 42
```

Finally, note that lenses compose.  We could have also written this:

```
const ageLens = idx => compose(lensIndex(idx), lensProp('age')).
```

Lens composition can be very powerful.

You can see this in action on the **[Rand REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20people%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20%27fred%27%2C%20age%3A%2028%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20%27wilma%27%2C%20age%3A%2025%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%203%2C%20name%3A%20%27barney%27%2C%20age%3A%2027%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%204%2C%20name%3A%20%27betty%27%2C%20age%3A%2029%7D%2C%20%20%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20personIdx%20%3D%20name%20%3D%3E%20findIndex%28propEq%28%27name%27%2C%20name%29%2C%20people%29%0Aconst%20ageLens%20%3D%20idx%20%3D%3E%20lensPath%28%5Bidx%2C%20%27age%27%5D%29%0A%0Aconst%20wLens%20%3D%20ageLens%28personIdx%28%27wilma%27%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20newPeople%20%3D%20over%28wLens%2C%20age%20%3D%3E%20age%20%2B%201%2C%20people%29%0A%0AnewPeople)**.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
var org = 
  [
    {name:"one",age:1}
    ,{name:"two",age:2}
  ]
;
var newArray =
  org
  .map(
    (x,index)=>
      index === 1
      ?Object.assign(
        {}
        ,x
        ,{name:"new name"}
      )
      :x
  )
;
```